# Why divide 1.0/0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in this (C?) example?

Tags: c, random, bit-manipulation

I am reading [Game AI Pro 1](http://www.gameaipro.com/GameAIPro/GameAIPro_Chapter03_Advanced_Randomness_Techniques_for_Game_AI.pdf), and in Chapter 3 on "Advanced Randomness..." I ran across a line of code I don't understand. The code is a Gaussian(ish) pseudorandom number generator returning values from -3.0 to 3.0 inclusive. The comment at the end is about the percentages of numbers falling within the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd standard deviations:

```
unsigned long seed = 61829450;
double GaussianRand()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        unsigned long holdseed = seed;
        seed ^ = << 13;
        seed ^ = seed >> 17;
        seed ^ = seed << 5;
        long r = (Int64)(holdseed + seed);
        sum + = (double)r * (1.0/0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
    }
    return sum; //returns [-3.0, 3.0] at (66.7%, 95.8%, 100%)
}
```

I think I have a rough idea of how the bit shifting and XORing produces pseudo-random numbers and I understand how the summation gives a rough Gaussian distribution. What I don't understand is the expression `(double)r * (1.0/0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)`. I imagine there is some bit or casting trick going on here, but I'm not sure what it is. Why do this division and then multiplication?

Comment: It's not a weird trick, just scaling.

Comment: Adding to what @Harold said, it's dividing 1 by a very large number in order to force the final result to be in the range [0, 1).

Comment: Ah, so I guess `r` is in the range [0,MAX_LONG] and this scales it to [0,1]

Comment: It's signed so [-1, 1], almost - actually it looks a bit suspicious since MIN_LONG multiplied by this fraction would be just slightly less than -1, however it may round the right way I'm not sure.

Comment: I think since holdseed and seed are unsigned longs, the value gets truncated to a positive signed long when it's assigned to r, so it's always positive. At least that seems like the intention.

Comment: Casting to signed can produce a negative number here, and it *should*, otherwise the result is in [0, 3] but it promises it will be in [-3, 3]

Comment: @xdhmoore It doesn't get truncated, it's reinterpreted, `r` isn't always positive.

Comment: @harod, luk32: Yeah, that makes sense. each iteration has to be [-1.0, 1.0]. Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand it now, thanks. If  someone posts an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If you don't get an answer in the next couple of days, and you think one would be helpful to others, you can post your own answer, and accept it after another 48 hours.

Comment: Your function's name is a lie.  Summing three uniform(-1,1) distributed numbers does not produce a Gaussian.

Comment: Gaussian-ish? It's supposed to be a ranged approximation for generating random numbers in the context of game AI programming...